# How to show that the boundary of $(0,1)$ is $\{0,1\}$?

Tags: general-topology

I am aware that this result is obvious, but for some reason I am tripping up on the proof. Essentially, I want to show that, taking $0$ for example, that for any $r>0$, $B(0,r)$ contains a point of $(0,1)$ and its complement. It contains $0$, so it definitely contains an element of the complement.

Now, I am struggling to show that it will contain an element of $(0,1)$. My argument would be that for any $B(0,r)$, we can simply pick a point in $(0,r)$, and since such a point is "closer", we should be good to go. I tried doing something with the triangle inequality but that didn't work out.

It seems like that using this "ordering" property of the reals is outside of the bounds of the metric space axioms that I studied. Or is this correct?

I realize that this is only half of the proof to show what the boundary is, but this is the part that I am struggling with.

Comment: $\pm r/2$ for $0$, $1\pm r/2$ for 1. This only shows $\{0,1\}$ is a subset of the boundary, however.

Comment: $B(0,r)$ will creep to the right a little bit, and that will hit $(0,1)$.

Comment: I don’t think you should hobble yourself by ignoring facts you know about the real number system.

Answer (score 1):

The closure of $(a,b)$ is the smallest closed subset containing $(a,b)$. It is easily verifiable (and intuitively clear) that the closure is $[a,b]$. The interior of a set A is the largest open set contained in A. The boundary of a set A is defined as $\overline{A}\backslash int(A)$. Hence, the boundary of $(a,b)$ is $\{$ a,b $\}$

Note: $\overline{A}\backslash int(A)$ = $\overline{A} \cap \overline{X \backslash A} $

Comment: Well, not always.  For many, the boundary of $A$ is defined to be $\overline{A} \cap \overline{X\setminus A}$, which also seems to be the definition OP is using.

Comment: @Randall, they are equivalent definitions. The complement of $int(A)$ is $X\backslash \overline{A}$

Comment: Yes, I know, but as a beginner OP may not.

Comment: I know they're the same, but I am wondering if there's a way to proceed with what I've done so far.

Comment: There must be an innocent typo in your comment.  That $X\setminus int(A)$ is $X\setminus \overline{A}$ is false by considering $A=(0,1)$ in $X=\mathbb{R}$ in the ordinary topology.

Comment: @Randall, you’re right. I meant $\overline{X \backslash A}$, which is what I wrote in my edit. Clearly, $int(A) \neq  \overline{A}$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply. Intuitively, by drawing a picture, you can see that if you set the radius of a circle around $0$ (the proof for the other endpoint is similar), *and* that radius is less than 1, it will contain both a point within and without the interval.

[image]

Hence, all we need to do is to rigorously construct two points such that:

1. For the first point - call it $P_1$, we have $0 - r < P_1 < 0$. Thus $P_1 \notin (0, 1)$, nor is it the putative boundary point, $0$. And
2. For the second point - call it $P_2$, we have $0 < P_2 < 0 + r$. Thus $P_2 \in (0, 1)$, and also is not the putative boundary point.

The answer?

Find the midpoints of the relevant intervals: take $P_1 := \frac{r}{2}$ and $P_2 := -\frac{r}{2}$, so long as $0 < r < 1$. Since any such value of $r$ will work, this shows every such open ball around $0$ contains a point both inside ($P_2$) and outside ($P_1$) the interval, no matter how small the ball. Now repeat an analogous construction for the other boundary point. QED.